# Wrestling with SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this in a MySQL db:

```
table Message
    sender_id int
    recipient_id int
    created datetime
    [title, body, etc... omitted]
```

Is it possible to get from this, in a single query, a list of all the users who have been communicating with a given user with id N (meaning N appears in either `sender_id` or `recipient_id`), ordered by `created`, including the most recent value of `created`, without duplicates (no sender/recipient pairs N, M and M, N)?

I'm pretty sure the answer is No, but I'm having trouble convincing myself. Afternoon mental dullness.

If No, what's the most efficient alternative you would recommend?

---

EDIT: holy crap, Stack Overflow is hopping these days. 8 answers before I realize I forgot to specify that I would like to have the most-recent value of `created` present along with the other user ID in each row.

Comment: Everything sounds pretty simple except the 'no sender/recipient pairs' duplicate part

Comment: What does 'M' represent in your requirements?  Are you saying you don't want self-references?

Comment: M is the other user's ID. All I want in the end is a list of M's and their associated most-recent create times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT x.friend,
       MAX(x.created)
  FROM (SELECT t.recipient_id 'friend',
               t.created
          FROM MESSAGE t
         WHERE t.sender_id = @id 
        UNION
        SELECT r.sender_id 'friend',
               r.created
          FROM MESSAGE r
         WHERE r.recipient_id = @id) x
GROUP BY x.friend
```

Comment: i had just finished writing up my own version of this from your original posting, but i deleted it since you should get the credit

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct recipient_id
FROM Message
WHERE sender_id = @id

UNION

SELECT distinct sender_id
FROM Message
WHERE recipient_id = @id
```

The union clause will remove duplicates across the two queries.  Actually looking at it you won't need the distinct's either as the union will do that for you too (anyone any idea if it's more efficient to use distinct to pre-filter the clauses or just let the union handle all the duplication?)

Comment: Myself I'd just make a view then use that to join back to the tables for any additional fields

Comment: I guess UNION is probably faster, since DISTINCT is pretty slow. Also, only using DISTINCT would still allow duplicates, when communication with another person happens both through sending and receiving...

Comment: You don't need the `DISTINCT` if you're going to be using `UNION` - you would if you were using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Unless there are tens of thousands of rows involved then there's not going to be a big efficiency hit and having a view of distinct ids available for use elsewhere is nicely modular and easy to understand

Comment: In fact, we're asked to include the most recent created date per user => you'll have to include group by clauses :)

Comment: I don't like Unions. They are very slow on some dbms.

Comment: heh, I posted my original answer before he added the rider about created.  But I still think using this as a view and joining back is simpler to understand for ongoing maintenance purposes

Comment: @Cruachan: Been there, loosing out to changing requirements :/

Answer (score 1):

No, it's pretty simple to do.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(sender_id=4, recipient_id, sender_id) AS partner_id
FROM message
WHERE sender_id=4 OR recipient_id=4
```

Comment: This way you don't need an UNION.
Obviously you have to replace 4 with your users' ID.

Comment: ah, this is close. unfortunately i was unclear and i also need the timestamp itself, which breaks distinct, i think?

Comment: Why would it break the DISTINCT?

Comment: One more thing, though: DISTINCT is usually pretty slow. Usually GROUP BY is faster, but I'm not sure how to apply that in this case. Maybe somebody else can help with that...

Comment: because if i do "select distinct IF(sender_id=4, recipient_id, sender_id) AS partner_id, created" then i get duplicate partner_ids

Comment: Ah right. That means we have to use GROUP BY. Let me check that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine :)

```
select id, max(created) as lastMessage
(
    select sender_id as id, created
    from Message
    union
    select recipient_id as id, created
    from Message
) as MergedMessage
where id = ?id
group by id
order by max(created) desc
```

That's it :

- without duplicates
- order by created desc

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you're having trouble convincing yourself, otherwise you wouldn't have asked. And I am pretty sure the answer is Yes. Yet, without knowing some particularities about the underlying data, it's a bit hard to find the right solution.

It probably goes into the direction of

```
select 
  sender_id,
  recipient_id
from
  message
where
 (sender_id    = n or 
  recipient_id = n   )
order by
  created desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will meet your requirements most:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE 
  user_id in 
    (select recipient_id FROM message m where m.sender_id = X)
  OR user_id in
    (select sender_id FROM message m where m.recipient_id = X)
order by
  created DESC
```

There are no duplicates, no unions and no SQL dialect specific stuff.